# How can I Approve a Merge Request using API in GitLab

Tags: git, asp.net-web-api, gitlab

how can I  "Approve" a Merge Request using api? 
I don't want to ACCEPT a Merge Request, just approve it with a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

As per [source](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/lib/api/merge_requests.rb) this is currently impossible. There currently is a [feature request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/201) pending on the enterprise edition issue tracker.